# Can Python Script executed in Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, python, windows-runtime, ironpython

Is there any way to execute python script in Windows Store App? I'm trying to use IronPython. Project compiles with no error but when I try to execute my python script I got `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` with below exception message.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Core, Version=5.0.5.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My C# code to execute python script is:

```
var setup = new ScriptRuntimeSetup();
setup.DebugMode = true;
setup.LanguageSetups.Add(Python.CreateLanguageSetup(null));

var runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
engine = runtime.GetEngineByTypeName(typeof(PythonContext).AssemblyQualifiedName);
string script = // Python Script;
engine.execute(script);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, IronPython doesn't support Windows Store apps right now. It's not compiled against the proper framework and still uses some APIs that are not supported in Store apps.